# Basic Multiplication with PHP

Tags: php, numbers

Consider the below code in PHP

```
$a = 8425996523 * 121212713;
$b = sprintf('%.2f', $a);  
$mul = gmp_mul("8425996523", "121212713");
```

Output is

```
1.0213378982814E+18 
1021337898281396864.00 
1021337898281396899
```

The actual answer is **1021337898281396899.** Hence, it is clear that we need to use any libraries like **gmp_mul** to do arithmetic with large numbers.

My question is, how to identify such errors?
ie, when PHP does  a calculation like

> 8425996523 * 121212713

, how can I identify that the result is not correct?

One way I see is to check for E and assume that whenever we forcefully convert such numbers, the errors exits.

Comment: That `E` is presentation, not storage of the number.... the number is stored as a float... but if you need that guarantee of precision, then use gmp from the start, don't do integer math and then test to see if the result is a float and redo using gmp because you're just adding overhead

Comment: Also, can anybody tell why this precision error occurs?

Comment: It happens because computers store numbers in a binary form and in a limited size (32-bit or 64-bit) - it's not PHP specific, but applies to almost every language ever implemented on computers -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$b = sprintf('%.2d', $a);
```

Instead of

```
$b = sprintf('%.2f', $a);
```

Here's a screenshot of the source code to show the difference:

---

[image]

Comment: This will not help . This will also give the answer as 1021337898281396864.00 where the actual answer is 1021337898281396899

Comment: Helps me... See screenshot on last revision.

Comment: My php does not give me this result. May be this is working in 64 bit and not in 32 bit

Comment: pl provide the php version and os(32 or 64 bit) you are using